# Atlas V RD-180 Analysis

Tags: engine-design, combustion, turbopump, atlas-v, rd-180

I was tasked with researching certain properties of the RD-180 engine. I am finding contradictory information, or I am unable to find it at all.

I am looking for the following information

- Mixture Ratio(chamber and preburner)
- Pump and Turbine Types
- Pump and Turbine Speeds
- Pump and Turbine Mass flows and head gains

Does anyone know this information? Or know of where I can find this information? I found Mixture ratio of both 2.72([source](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20010067310/downloads/20010067310.pdf)) and 2.6([source](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19950013232/downloads/19950013232.pdf)), not sure which is correct, or if it is for chamber or preburner.

My googling skills are not enough for me to find this info, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The 2.6 vs 2.72 might be total propellant flow vs chamber propellant only -- the preburner might run a little richer -- but that's just a guess. It could as easily be two different versions of the engine.

Comment: Perhaps some of what you are looking for is here http://lpre.de/energomash/RD-180/index.htm but it's a struggle for me to wade through the machine translation.